# I've started a panic with my index out of range, and I can't get out

Tags: string, go, types, panic

I'm writing this program to become comfortable with types (not objects!).

The basic premise is the user enters an animal name (cow, snake bird), then an action (eat, move, sound.) My code then looks it up and returns the value.

So, the user entry is suppose to be on ONE line separated by a " ". I use strings.Split.

I'm getting a "panic" notice when the user only enters a single char. I'm thinking this panic arises out of the compiler trying to "split" a single char.

TWO Questions:
1. Am I right?
2. How do I fix it?

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

//Create our type object.
type animal struct {
    aType, eats, moves, sounds string
}

//Create our methods.
func (animal animal) info (querie string) {
    if querie == "eats" {
        fmt.Printf("The animal, %s , eats %s\n ", animal.aType, animal.eats)
    } else if querie == "moves" {
        fmt.Printf("The animal, %s , moves by  %s\n ", animal.aType, animal.moves)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("The animal, %s , makes the sound %s\n ", animal.aType, animal.sounds)
    }
}

func main() {
    //Now create our animals

    cow := animal{aType:"cow", eats: "grass", moves: "walking", sounds: "moo"}
    bird := animal{aType:"bird", eats: "worms", moves: "flying", sounds: "peep"}
    snake := animal{aType:"snake", eats: "mice", moves: "slithering", sounds: "hiss"}
    // need a boolean to perpetuate our loop
    var flag bool = true

    for flag {
        fmt.Println("Remember enter X to exit")
        fmt.Printf(">please enter your (format: type & information) request -> ")
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        scanner.Scan()
        request := scanner.Text()

        //Capture user entered data

        typed := strings.Split(request, " ")[0]
        if typed == "X" {
            flag = false
            break
        }
        infoe := strings.Split(request, " ")[1]

        // contruct the logic tree. 

        if !((infoe == "eat") || (infoe == "move") || (infoe == "speak")) {
            switch typed {
            case "cow": 
                cow.info(infoe)

            case "snake": 
                snake.info(infoe)

            case "bird": 
                bird.info(infoe)
            default: 
                fmt.Println("I don't know about that animal.")          
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("I don't have that informtion")
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What panic? The panic includes a stack trace that tells you exactly where the problem occurred. Include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the scanner outside the loop to avoid discarding buffered data.  Break when Scan() returns false. Check for and handle invalid input.

```
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
for {
    fmt.Println("Remember enter X to exit")
    if !scanner.Scan() {
        break
    }
    request := scanner.Text()
    parts := strings.Split(request, " ")
    if parts[0] == "X" {
        break
    }
    if len(parts) < 2 {
        fmt.Println("bad input")
        break
    }

    typed := parts[0]
    infoe := parts[1]

    ...
```

Comment: Just great. I am very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify your code, I would suggest using `fmt.Scanf` as shown below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var animal, action string

    fmt.Printf("Enter animal: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &animal)
    fmt.Printf("Enter action: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &action)

    fmt.Printf("Animal was %s and action was %s", animal, action)
}
```

Also am not sure why there are multiple downvotes. Is it the problem with the way the code is written? I think that's ok if someone is just trying to learn the language. First get it working and then focus on other things.

Once you are comfortable with the language, you can go through points listed in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)